# read 1 lakh (0.1 million) items from list using power automate

Tags: power-automate

Is it possible to read list items (having more than 1 lakh or 0.1 million count) using power automate and the data has to be exported to CSV Format..

please let us know if any body has similar solutions..

Answer (score 0):

You can import lists into excel and then save as csv. If you need to have this on a schedule, you can read lists with powershell and do the export from there. Any solution is going to be pretty slow...